# Doing UPDATE SET across two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will update a field for records in a table that match certain conditions. I am mostly there but it is updating every record in the table rather than just the 33 that match the condition. This is what I have:

```
UPDATE invitations 
   SET accepted = 'true' 
FROM invitations i 
  INNER JOIN users u ON i.parent_email=u.email 
WHERE u.encrypted_password <> '' 
  AND i.accepted='false'
```

Basically I'm trying to set the accepted field true in the invitations table, if the corresponding record in the users table has a password set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :)

```
UPDATE invitations SET accepted = 'true'
WHERE (
   SELECT encrypted_password
   FROM users
   WHERE invitations.parent_email=users.email
) <> ''
AND invitations.accepted='false'
```

Answer (score 3):

The [PostgreSQL documentation of `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html) says:

> Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list).

So, I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE invitations i
SET i.accepted = 'true'
FROM users u
WHERE i.parent_email=u.email AND u.encrypted_password <> '' AND i.accepted='false'
```